# download from url with executor service

Tags: android, url, download, executorservice

I used the code below in executor service to download a file from URL. It downloads the file but size is 0 bytes. code works fine when I use asyncTask. but when I put it in executor service doesn't work.

Any ideas why the download won't be complete?

onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        String url = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file_example_JPG_100kB.jpg";
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pool.execute(new NetworkService(url));

            }
        });
```

NetworkService class:

```
private class NetworkService implements Runnable {
        private String url;

        public NetworkService(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dlFile(url);
        }

        private String dlFile(String surl) {

            try {
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(surl);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                        return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                    input = connection.getInputStream();
                    String title = URLUtil.guessFileName(String.valueOf(url), null, null);
                    output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()  + "/" + title);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return e.toString();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (output != null)
                            output.close();
                        if (input != null)
                            input.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.disconnect();
                }
            } finally {
            }
            return  null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `File direct` You are not using that instance.

Comment: Better: `if ( ! direct.mkdirs()) return;`

Comment: input/output, you are not reading from input nor writing to output. `It downloads the file but size is 0 bytes.` No. It downloads nothing as you are not reading from input.

Comment: ok. I changed the code and removed mkdir. doesn't `input = connection.getInputStream();` read from input?

Comment: No. it only gives you the input stream. After that you can read from the stream. I wonder what code you have in your asynctask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you should do and verify.

1 - First of all, make sure you have granted the required permissions to save file to the storage.

> - READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> - WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
> - INTERNET

2 - Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your manifest file's application tag for android 10 and later versions.

3 - Correct your `FileOutputStream` initialisation, because

```
val direct = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/test_files")
```

You are creating a path above in test_files Folder, but in `FileOutputStream` you have specified different path. So, the correct line should be

```
output = FileOutputStream( direct + "/" + title)
```

And finally, add the following line after `output =` line to write image to the buffer, because you are reading the `InputStream` but you are not writing it on the buffer. That is why, it only create the path in storage, but do not write file to that path.

```
val buf = ByteArray(1024)
var len: Int
while (input.read(buf).also { len = it } > 0) {
      output.write(buf, 0, len)
}
```

**PS: I have written the code in Kotlin and tested it on Android 10, It works fine**.

I hope this helps. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it help.

Comment: I write this code in java and did it`while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }`

Comment: do you know how I can add cookie to this code?

Comment: I have never used cookies. I'm sorry I can not help you with that right now :)